# How to convert a date string read from a file into a datetime date object?

Tags: python

The code I have reads a file, and you end up with this variable

```
joinDate = 31/05/2020
```

Now, even if I put it into 31-05-2020 I still get the error

> ValueError: time data ' 31/05/2020' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'

The line im using to try and translate it is this:

```
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('1-1-1990', '%d-%m-%Y')
       end = datetime.datetime.strptime('31-12-2020', '%d-%m-%Y')     
       date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(joinDate, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

The start and End is meant to be there for a range, I have tried a few things to fix it but haven't gotten anywhere. I have also tried strftime and still doesn't work. Any help is very welcomed, thank you.

Here is some code that shows that brings up the error message, if there is some odd bits (like choice = "Y" thats because this is just a snippet of code.

```
import datetime

def dateChecker():
    Date = joinDate.replace('/', '-', 3)
    print(Date)
    Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(joinDate, '%d-%m-%Y')
    try:
        start = datetime.datetime.strptime('1-1-1990', '%d-%m-%Y')
        end = datetime.datetime.strptime('31-12-2020', '%d-%m-%Y')     
        date1 = datetime.datetime.strftime(Date, '%d-%m-%Y')
        return True
        if start <= date1 and date1 <= end:
            print('it worked!')
    except (ValueError): 
        if date_check_read == 1:
             print(joinDate)
             print('Error with the recorded date.')
             print('Ending program now.')
             exit()
    else:
        print('Error with the date, Please input again.')

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    choice = "Y"
    for line in f:
        if choice == "Y":
            nameLast, nameFirst, joinDate, rewardPoint = line.split(',')
            dateChecker()
            print(f'Last name : {nameLast}\n'
                  f'First name:{nameFirst}\n'
                  f'Date      :{joinDate}\n'
                  f'Points    :{rewardPoint}')
```

Comment: Just curious...do you have `datetime` imported?

Comment: I see a leading space before 31. Can you do a strip() before passing it to strptime

Comment: @vivi17 Yeah I got datetime imported!

Comment: @Luv I went ahead and removed it in the text file, and nope, still a error.

Comment: can you give a code example (or part of the your code) that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please check the format you are passing. In case your date string has '/' use this format `'31/12/2020', '%d/%m/%Y'`

Comment: I copied code and what seemed to be a problem on my local machine is that joinDate doesn't have a `'` surrounding it. Added that, it worked just fine. Oh and I changed the time format from 31/05/2020 to 31-05-2020
[EDIT]: `'31/05/2020', '%d/%m/%y'` should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

In your code,, the line `Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(joinDate, '%d-%m-%Y')` try to convert the string `joinDate` which is currently equals to `31/05/2020`. This is why you have an error.
You should try `Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date, '%d-%m-%Y')`.

The code below is functionnal:

```
import datetime

def dateChecker():
    Date = joinDate.replace('/', '-', 3)
    print(Date)
    Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    print(Date)

def dateChecker2():
    print(joinDate)
    Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(joinDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    print(Date)

joinDate = '31/05/2020'
dateChecker()
dateChecker2()
```